# Extracting northing easting using autocad

Tags: coordinates, gis, autocad

I have a DWG file and with some polylines drawed there.

I would like to extract the coordinates of these polylines and save them into csv using easting northing coord system.

is it possible to do something like that in Autocad?

Br,
Ioannis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write an autocad .NET plugin (c#), which iterates through all lines of a specific layer and exports each point of the line to a csv. See https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/video/youtube/watch-v-5a50QULamuU.html for first examples. Here is a basic example, which creates a plugin, which can be started with the command "Action". But the part with the line export is missing. This plugin generates random points and lines in the drawing in each layer. There are several other  tutorials for autocad API. You can use this example code for starting your project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;

[assembly: CommandClass(typeof(AcadLayerPlugin.LayerPlugin))]

namespace AcadLayerPlugin
{
    public class LayerPlugin
    {
        [CommandMethod("Action")]
        public static void Action()
        {

            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Huhu");
            Database database = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
            try
            {
                using (Transaction transaction = database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    SymbolTable symTable = (SymbolTable)transaction.GetObject(database.LayerTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    foreach (ObjectId id in symTable)
                    {
                        LayerTableRecord symbol = (LayerTableRecord)transaction.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);

                        //TODO: Access to the symbol
                        //Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.WriteMessage(string.Format("\nName: {0}", symbol.Name));
                        // Open the Block table for read
                        BlockTable acBlkTbl;
                        acBlkTbl = transaction.GetObject(database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTable;

                        // Open the Block table record Model space for write
                        BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec;
                        acBlkTblRec = transaction.GetObject(acBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
                                                        OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

                        // Create a line that starts at 5,5 and ends at 12,3
                        Random r = new Random();
                        Line acLine = new Line(new Point3d(r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble()),
                                               new Point3d(r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble()));
                        acLine.LayerId = id;
                        Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.DBPoint point = new DBPoint(new Point3d(r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble()));
                        point.LayerId = id;

                        MText acMText = new MText();
                        acMText.Location = new Point3d(r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble(), r.NextDouble());
                        acMText.Width = 8;
                        acMText.Contents = "Ohlsen was here.";
                        acMText.LayerId = id;

                        acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acLine);
                        acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(point);
                        acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acMText);
                        transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acLine, true);
                        transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(point, true);
                        transaction.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acMText, true);
                        Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.WriteMessage(string.Format("\nName: {0}", symbol.Name));
                        // Save the new object to the database
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }catch(System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```